# MS SQL convert date 103 ordering problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to convert a Datetime from 29/07/2011 00:00:00 this from this format to just 29/07/2011. I do this with a SELECT statement

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), thisDate, 103) As thisDate ... ORDER BY thisDate
```

This gives an order of something like this

```
01/08/2011
02/08/2011
05/06/2011
08/07/2011
14/07/2011
21/06/2010
21/07/2011
23/07/2011
24/07/2011
24/07/2011
```

However when I use `101` or `102` formatting the results are correct and the dates are ordered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because SQL server is trying to sort based on a text string which gets sorted alphabetically, instead of sorting by date.

Try doing this to your query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), thisDate, 103) As newDate, thisDate
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY thisDate ASC
```

Comment: How does the string get sorted alphabetically when the entire string is just numbers and "/" and no alphabets? Also then why does `102` and `101` sort just fine? They're both only numbers and dots/hyphens

Comment: @bash- SQL server doesn't think of the thisDate as an object of type Date after you convert it to an nvarchar(10). Instead it sees it as a string. Alphabetical sorting works for numbers and punctuation too. 1 comes before 2, which comes before 3, and so on...

Comment: It's simple... in your example year is always the same. And in 101 and 102 modes month comes BEFORE days :) Just look at the modes: 101 mm/dd/yy, 
102 yy.mm.dd, 
103 dd/mm/yy

Answer (score 2):

You can order by field of type DATETIME.
In you example you need to rename the alias:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), thisDate, 103) As thatDate ... ORDER BY thisDate
```

Comment: worked like a charm, but I still don't understand why `102` and `101` sorts fine.

Comment: because you have sorted by STRINGS, not by DATE, and, as strings, '14/07/2011' < '21/06/2010', but '06/21/2010' < '07/14/2011'. Dates are the same, string are different.

Answer (score 2):

Don't convert datetime to string - converting for display purpose should be done at client side, according to the client setup. For ordering the resultset you should use date field directly, no need to convert it, it would be just waste of resources.

The `102` style "works" because it formats date as "yy.mm.dd" which sorts "correctly" (can be ordered as string according the same rules as dates). So does `112` ("yyyymmdd") and some others, but `101` shouldn't work as you expect (it's US format "mm/dd/yyyy").